# How is the matrix P is found and why using Smith Normal Form?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, smith-normal-form

Here is the question I am trying to solve from Allen Hatcher's book:

Compute the simplicial homology groups of the Klein bottle using the $\Delta$-complex structure described at the beginning of this section.

And here is the solution I found online for this question:

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

But I do not know how is the matrix P is found and why using Smith Normal Form ?

Comment: The second solution doesn't use $P$ at all. Do you understand the approach presented there?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I did not mean to include the second solution in my question, though I understand it yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions directly:

1. The columns of $P$ are taken from the coefficients of $a,b,c$ in the equations
   $$
   \partial U = (1)a + (1)b + (-1)c,\\
   \partial L = (1)a + (-1)b + (1)c.
   $$
2. The Smith normal form of an $m \times n$ matrix $P$ gives you a convenient way to identify the quotient $\Bbb Z^m/P(\Bbb Z^n)$ up to isomorphism (where $P(\Bbb Z^n)$ denotes the image of the map $x \mapsto Px$).